# Display a placeholder image while image is loading from server

Tags: angularjs, haml

I am building a website on rails using haml and angularJs.The images are loading from server. I want a placeholder image to be displayed if the image is not loading or its taking too much time. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry, but that's not how it works around here. Please show some effort, and some code, and ask a very specific question.

Comment: an answer with the same efforts as the questions : please see the "load" event. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

So you will add a directive, which will get the original-src attribute and will replace the placeholder. As you can see it binds on the load event. Hope it helps.

Angular js:

```
app.directive('original', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { original-src: '@' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('load', function() {
            element.attr('src', scope.original-src);
        });
    }
  };
});
```

your html

```
<img original-src="original.jpg" src="placeholder.jpg" />
```

Comment: I am using ng-src instead of src.Will this still work?